# PHP: Add months/days/years to user supplied date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

***** SOLVED *****

I have a small program where I get a date from a user - (mm/dd/yyy) - then allow them to add x number of days, months, or years. I've been trying to use the 'strtotime' function but I'm not sure if I am understanding it right.

My code is below. Say, for example, $od (original date) was 7/24/2015. The $d, $m, and $y variables are read from the form filled out by the user. These could be 0's or a user-supplied value.

Before spending hours on this one simple task, I thought I'd ask if I should be approaching this in a different fashion and/or using another function.

```
    // Function to determine new date
function newDate($od, $d, $m, $y) { 
    $newDate = Date($od, strtotime('+ $d days'));
    $newDate = Date($od, strtotime('+ $m months'));
    $newDate = Date($od, strtotime('+ $y years'));

    if ($od != $newDate) {
        return $newDate;
    }
    else if ($od == $newDate ){
        return '[no change]';
    }
    else {
        return '[error occurred]';
    }
}
```

EDIT: Trying now with the interval date as suggested. Can you not parse the interval string together? I feel like this should work (results in some 'non-object' error):

```
    $newDate = $od;
    $newDate->add(new DateInterval('P'.$m.'M'.$d.'D'.$y.'Y'));
    echo $newDate;
    if ($od != $newDate) {
        return $newDate->format('mm/dd/yyyy');
```

EDIT: I figured it out - you can't have '0's in the string so the function won't be as clean as I had hoped.

***** SOLVED *****

Comment: The DateInterval needs to be defined from largest unit to smallest. So YMD, not MDY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way : DateTime::add -- date_add — Adds an amount of days, months, years, hours, minutes and seconds to a DateTime object 
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php 
Using native functions is always fastest, and in your case seems the proper way to go!

Comment: Remember that DateTime::add modifies the DateTime object - it does not return a new object. If using PHP 5.5 or higher, there is also the DateTimeImmutable class - DateTimeImmutable::add returns a new object which is handy if you need to retain the original DateTime object as well as the modified one.